# Communication Notifications Requirements for iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications

Perhaps I missed the specific WWDC video, but there is a concept increasingly predominant on iOS amongst chat apps where the avatar of the sender and reciever is observed within the PUSH notifications. Articles exist on Apples official documentation where it implicitly suggests that such a Push notification where Avatars are utilised would only be possible for apps that make use of communication UX.

This is vague.

My question for clarification which will affect the direction of our commercial app used by millions is quite simply can we make use of this functionality for a uni directional communication app?